# Localizar indice de elemento dentro da matriz em Python

Tags: python

Estou tentando localizar o índice de um número dentro de uma lista de listas preestabelecidas. O programa reconhece o número mas diz que ele não consta na lista.

```python
i=[[33,59],[34,60],[35,61],[36,62],[37,63],[38,64],[39,65],[40,66],[41,67],[42,68],[43,69],[44,70],[45,71],[46,72],[47,73],[48,74],[49,75],[50,76],[51,77],[52,78],[53,79],[54,80],[55,81],[56,82],[57,83],[58,84]]
senha="senhasenha"
x=""
k=""
y=0
for a in senha:
    j=(ord(a)-97)
    x+=(chr(i[j][y]))
    y+=1
    if(y>1):
        y=0
print (x)
for w in x:
  k=int(ord(w))
  print(i.index(k))
```

o retorno fica assim

```
`3?.B!M%H(;
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 16, in
>   
>       print(i.index(k)) ValueError: 51 is not in list`

como posso fazer para acessar esse indice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando acessar o número através da lista de listas. Para que funcione, você deverá acessar o número nas listas que estão dentro da lista `i`. Implemente isso:

```
for w in x:
    k = ord(w)
    for lista in i:
        if k in lista:
            print("j =",i.index(lista),"y =",lista.index(k),"letra =",chr(i.index(lista)+97))
```

No código acima, eu obtenho a variável `j` recebendo a posição da lista dentro da lista de listas e obtenho a variável `y` recebendo a posição do valor na lista. Também coloquei para imprimir a letra daquela chave, fazendo o caminho inverso de gerar uma chave da letra.